# Play Framework : Sending CSV file as an attachment

Tags: java, csv, playframework

How to send a CSV file as an attachment in Play framework? I looked into the Play documentation by I didn't find what I'm looking for. I know I can return an input stream like that : `ok(java.io.InputStream content, int chunkSize)` but how to create and send the content to the csv file?

Comment: Please add one extra `java` or `scala` tag to your play question to clarify which API you're using

Comment: I'm not allowed to put more than 2 tags.

Comment: I suppose it's Java. Otherwise tell me to change to Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Play** makes it easy to manipulate a **HTTPResponse**. You can find in [the manual](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaResponse), how to add headers, set cookies etc. in a response.

The implementation differs according to the use case:

- Some string source is converted to csv file while sending to the client.
- An existing csv file is sent to the client.

**Sending string as CSV file in a HTTPResponse**

*Play 2.4*

```
static private final String CSV_FILE_NAME = "demo.csv";
...
public Result string2CsvFile() {  
   String csvContent = "f1,f2,f3,f4";  
   response().setContentType("text/csv");  
   response().setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION,   
       String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", CSV_FILE_NAME));  
   return ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(csvContent.getBytes()));  
}
```

*Play 2.5*

```
static private final String CSV_FILE_NAME = "demo.csv";
...
public Result string2CsvFile() {  
   String csvContent = "f1,f2,f3,f4";  
    response().setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
            String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", CSV_FILE_NAME));
    return ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(csvContent.getBytes())).as("text/csv");
}
```

**Sending existing CSV file in a HTTPResponse**

*Play 2.4*

```
static private final String CSV_FILE_NAME = "demo.csv";
...
public Result attachCsvFile() {  
    response().setContentType("text/csv");
    response().setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
            String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", CSV_FILE_NAME));
    return ok(Play.application().getFile(CSV_FILE));
}
```

*Play 2.5*

```
 static private final String CSV_FILE_NAME = "demo.csv";
 ...
 public Result attachCsvFile() {  
    response().setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
       String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", CSV_FILE_NAME));
    return ok(Play.current().getFile(CSV_FILE)).as("text/csv");
}
```

Comment: This link is broken. If you have other resources. please share

Comment: Please see the answer - instead of broken link

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking to do something like this:

```
 public Result downloadCsv() {
    response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=example.csv");
    return ok(Play.application().getFile("conf/resources/example.csv"));
}
```

Comment: You could add a `response().setContentType("text/csv")` to indicate that it's CSV. Apart from that CSV files are just text files.

Answer (score 0):

PlayFramework already have [a method to delivery files as attachments](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/StatusHeader.html#sendFile-java.io.File-boolean-) (see [`Results.ok` too](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#ok-java.io.File-boolean-)). Just do the following:

```
public Result deliveryFile() {
    File file = ...
    boolean inline = true;
    return ok(file, inline);
}
```

Keep in mind that is up to you to ensure the file exists and is readable.